# how to get progress logging details in aws sdk version 2

Tags: java, swing, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am working on java project in which I am using **AWS SDK version 2** for AWS services like uploading ,downloading, ACL etc.
I am using **S3client** for AWS operation and I want to show progress of upload , download and other operations.
I am using **S3TransactionManager** for progress.

Code are following:

```
     S3TransferManager s3TransferManager = S3TransferManager
            .builder()
            .s3ClientConfiguration(S3ClientConfiguration.builder()
                    .region(Region.of(region))
                    .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider).build())
            .build();
 FileUpload upload = s3TransferManager.uploadFile(u -> u.source(Paths.get("file1.txt"))
            .putObjectRequest(p -> p.bucket("bucket").key("file1.txt"))
            .overrideConfiguration(o -> o.addListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())));
    upload.completionFuture().join();
```

output:

```
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: Transfer complete!
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: Transfer initiated...
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |                    | 0.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |=                   | 5.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |==                  | 10.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |===                 | 15.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |====                | 20.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |=====               | 25.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |======              | 30.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |=======             | 35.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |========            | 40.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |=========           | 45.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |==========          | 50.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |===========         | 55.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |============        | 60.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |=============       | 65.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |==============      | 70.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |===============     | 75.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |================    | 80.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |=================   | 85.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |==================  | 90.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |=================== | 95.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:04:57 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
INFO: |====================| 100.0%
Aug 31, 2022 12:05:22 PM software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Logger info
PutObjectResponse: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@1b7643d[Completed normally]
INFO: Transfer complete!
```

Now my issue is that I am using **swing** for showing progress bar for uploading file.
**So how can I get progress details and can show in customized progress bar?**

Answer (score 0):

Create your own implementation of a `LoggingTransferListener` and write to the UI in your implementation.

Comment: Can you please write sample program of custom implementation of LoggingTransferListener